# How to add icon in select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-select2

I using select2 version 4

I try like this :

```
$("select02").select2({
    placeholder: "<i class='fa fa-sitemap'></i>Branch name",
});
```

But, it's not working

Demo is like this : http://jsfiddle.net/fc1qevem/8/

Any solution to solve my problem?

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code?
Is the stylesheet attached correctly?

Comment: @KarlGjertsen, http://jsfiddle.net/fc1qevem/8/

Answer (score 20):

Always read the reference/manual first!

From the official **select2** examples on their [web site](http://select2.github.io/examples.html#templating);

```
function formatState (state) {
  if (!state.id) { return state.text; }
  var $state = $(
    '<span><img src="vendor/images/flags/' +  state.element.value.toLowerCase() + 
'.png" class="img-flag" /> ' + 
state.text +     '</span>'
 );
 return $state;
};

$(".js-example-templating").select2({
  templateResult: formatState
});
```

**Gives you the result:**

[image: Select2 with icons]

Comment: This is not what he asked for. He wants to have an icon in the search field.

Comment: Thank you guy! I loved your response;

Comment: Always read the question before you answer :)

Answer (score 7):

Found this [How to add html placeholder to select2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17896075/how-to-add-html-placeholder-to-select2)

So what you need is:

```
$("select02").select2({
  placeholder: '<i class="fa fa-sitemap"></i>Branch name',
  escapeMarkup : function(markup) {
    return markup;
  }
});
```

Comment: this is the solution works for put icon inside the select2 both two attributes are needed to render the icon

Answer (score 4):

For Icons instead of img use:

```
function format (state) {
    if (!state.id) { return state.text; }
    return '<i class="fa fa-lg '+state.id.toLowerCase()+'"></i> '+state.text;
} 

$("#select2icon").select2({
    formatResult: format,
    formatSelection: format,
    escapeMarkup: function(m) { return m; }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Per [the migration guide](https://select2.org/upgrading/migrating-from-35#renamed-templating-options), versions after 3.5.x no longer use `formatResult` or `formatSelection`. These have been replaced with `templateResult` and `templateSelection`.

```js
function iconFromValue(val){
    if(val.element){
        val = `<span class="select2-option-img"><img src="${val.element.value}"><span> ${val.text}`;
    }
    return val;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.select2').select2({
        templateResult: iconFromValue,
        templateSelection: iconFromValue,
        escapeMarkup: function(m) { return m; }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example:

```
function format(state) {
    if (!state.id) 
        return state.text; // optgroup
    return "<img class='flag' src='images/flags/" + state.id.toLowerCase() + ".png'/>" + state.text;
}

$("#select2").select2({
    formatResult: format,
    formatSelection: format,
    escapeMarkup: function(m) { return m; }
});
```

user above js.

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it. You just need to add 'escapeMarkup'. See the code below.

```
var select02 = $('#select02');

$(select02).select2({
    data: [{
        id: 0,
        text: "test01"
    }, {
        id: 1,
        text: "test02"
    }, {
        id: 2,
        text: "test03"
    }, {
        id: 3,
        text: "test04"
    }, {
        id: 4,
        text: "test05"
    }],
     placeholder: "<i class='fa fa-sitemap'></i>Branch name",
     escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }
});
```